Disappearing fire simulation
I made fire in blender according to the attached video and everything worked fine. But after a few days when I opened the file again the fire did not work and you can only see the particles without fire.And all the data was in place without any change.
What could be the reason for this and how to solve it?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wOS_wvzhnA

Did you bake the simulation (particles and fire)? If not, you have to simulate it again every time you open Blender. If you did bake it, well only seeing the tutorial but nothing of your scene, no settings etc. it is almost impossible for us to find the specific point where you went wrong. And sorry, no offense - but it works like shown in the video, so there must be something you did incorrectly. Perhaps you only have to watch the video again thoroughly and make sure you do everything in the same way.

Thanks for the answer
